# Is it safe to use persistent connection using PHP mysqli interface?

Tags: php, mysqli, persistent-connection

There are quite a few blog/links which discourage usage of persistent connections, mainly because the cleanup needs to be done on client side, and cases where transactions/locks have to be correctly rolled back. However, those links are old, and not enirely in context of mysqli PHP interface.

I read the link : [The mysqli Extension and Persistent Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php)

It clearly suggests that it does most of the desired cleanup when a client terminates unexpectedly:

> - Rollback active transactions
> - Close and drop temporary tables
> - Unlock tables
> - Reset session variables
> - Close prepared statements (always happens with PHP)
> - Close handler
> - Release locks acquired with GET_LOCK()

Now that pretty much does most of the cleanup, including READ/WRITE locks on tables if any acquired. So I believe it should be safe. Can I be wrong?

Also, it says there are some performance penalty in form of extra time needed to do cleanup. I would like to know how much that may be in terms of millisecs? Can it ever be as large as say 100 ms?

> The automatic cleanup feature has advantages and disadvantages though.
>   The advantage is that the programmer no longer needs to worry about
>   adding cleanup code, as it is called automatically. However, the
>   disadvantage is that the code could potentially be a little slower, as
>   the code to perform the cleanup needs to run each time a connection is
>   returned from the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you really think you can trust an answer from anonymous passer-by more than official documentation page, that clearly answers your question.

But if you do - yes, you can believe it should be safe.

As of performance penalty, from the way it is asked, I believe you don't really need persistent connections at all.

Comment: So will time it takes for cleanup be more than db connection?